# Defining WebSphere MQ administrative subscriptions

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using IBM's WebSphere MQ, and having issues creating administrative subscriptions via scripts. One of the params expects an existing model queue but for some reason it is missing from our environment. Maybe that's an issue altogether but wondering is there a way to bypass the model queue and create a subscription anyways?

The link I'm looking at is the Messages & Codes manual section containing [AMQ8464](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqzao.doc/amq8.htm&resultof=%22amq8464%22). 
Please scroll down to see AMQ8464. I guess we're missing the `Insert_3` but hopefully there is a way around not having it. The full text of the error is as follows:

> If the command entered was Change or Display, the subscription
>    specified does not exist. If the command entered was Copy,
>   the source subscription does not exist. If the command entered was
>   Create, the system default MQ subscription does not exist.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I retagged this to [tag:websphere-mq] so it would be easier for WMQ folks to find. The [tag:websphere] tag gets app server admins and devs.

Answer (score 2):

This error can be thrown when attempting to copy or delete a subscription and the expected existing subscription isn't found.  Since you are attempting to define a subscription then we can assume that the last case described in the error manual is the one we want - `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB` does not exist.  This subscription is defined when the QMgr is created (assuming a v7.0 or greater version of WMQ).  There are two ways to get it back.

1. Define the subscription manually.  All that is required for this to work is to specify all the fields in the subscription.
2. Use the `strmqm -c` command [as described here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc/fa16090_.htm).  This will redefine any default system objects that have been manually deleted, including the default subscription.

The reason that #1 works is that WMQ will use whatever parameters that you provide on your `DEFINE` command and then any you leave out it looks at the `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB` object to determine the system local default value.  If you supply *all* of the values, then it has no need to look at the default object and just defines whatever you tell it.  That means you can define your own subscription or for that matter you can define `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB` just by specifying all the parms.  The following `DEFINE` statement recreates `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB` without having to stop and restart the QMgr using the `-c` option:

```
DEFINE SUB(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.SUB) + 
       TOPICSTR('') +
       TOPICOBJ('') +
       DEST('') +
       DESTQMGR('') +
       PUBAPPID('') +
       SELECTOR('') +
       USERDATA('') +
       PUBACCT(0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) + 
       DESTCORL(000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) +
       DESTCLAS(PROVIDED) +
       EXPIRY(UNLIMITED) + 
       PSPROP(MSGPROP) + 
       PUBPRTY(ASPUB) +
       REQONLY(NO) + 
       SUBSCOPE(ALL) + 
       SUBLEVEL(1) + 
       VARUSER(ANY) +
       WSCHEMA(TOPIC) +
       SUBUSER('')
```